# Linguistic Term for "Shame if something happened to it" type phrases

Tags: terminology

The phrase "you've got a nice [noun] here. Shame if something happened to it" has been a trope for years. It represents a type of communication where what the speaker intends to communicate is not actually what they say.

Is there a linguistic term for this? Subtext doesn't seem to fit because that implies that it is a secondary meaning, rather than the primary intended meaning.

Comment: Can you give a more clear example of this? What is the intention? To threaten? To compliment? Irony?

Comment: Yes, the trope meaning: If you don't do x, I'm gonna mess up your [whatever]. Yes, that is a rhetorical device. It's a litote (understatement for effect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common way to describe this is as **veiled** language.

> *veiled*   1    adj  A veiled comment is expressed in a disguised form rather than directly and openly.
>
> - *This last clause is a thinly-veiled threat to those who might choose to ignore the decree.*

[[Collins](https://mobile-dictionary.reverso.net/en/english-cobuild/veiled+threat)]

Comment: @Yosef I haven't seen your answer till now (1 hour after '1 hour ago'). 'Thinly veiled' is usually associated with criticism / threats, though not always ('thinly veiled plug / recommendation / endorsement / approval / praise), and OP's question allows for other examples (as DjinTonic reasons).

Answer (score 2):

**implicature**

> **n.** The action of implying a meaning beyone the literal sense of what is
> explicitly stated, e.g., saying *the frame is nice* and implying *I don't like the picture in it.*
> ■ a meaning so implied. (The New Oxford American Dictionary)

> An **implicature** is something the speaker suggests or implies with
> an utterance, even though it is not literally expressed. Implicatures
> can aid in communicating more efficiently than by explicitly saying
> everything we want to communicate. This phenomenon is part of
> pragmatics, a subdiscipline of linguistics. The philosopher H. P.
> Grice coined the term in 1975. Grice distinguished **conversational
> implicatures**, which arise because speakers are expected to respect
> general rules of conversation, and **conventional ones**, which are tied
> to certain words such as "but" or "therefore".  [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicature#:%7E:text=An%20implicature%20is%20something%20the,pragmatics%2C%20a%20subdiscipline%20of%20linguistics.)

> Consider the following example (lifted unashamedly from Steven
> Pinker’s book *The Stuff of Thought*):
>
> A gangster walks into a local restaurant. The restaurant has been
> doing well recently, and the local criminal gangs are aware of this
> fact. The gangster walks over to the restaurant owner, stares
> conspicuously around the room, and says **“This is real nice place you
> got here. It would be a shame if something happened to it.”**
>
> Ostensibly, the gangster’s statement is one of fact: depending on what
> the “something” in question is, it may indeed be a shame if it
> happened to the restaurant. But of course no one reading the statement
> really thinks it is as innocuous as that. Everyone knows that it
> constitutes a **thinly-veiled threat**. Why is this?
>
> The answer lies in something known as **conversational implicature,**
> which is the fancy label given to the mundane phenomenon that the
> semantic content of a particular utterance or sentence is not
> exhausted by the meaning of the words that make up that utterance.
> Which is to say: it is possible for an utterance to have an **implied
> meaning**, which is just as important and just as readily understood as
> that of its **explicit meaning**. Indeed, sometimes it is more important
> than the explicit meaning, as in the case of the gangster’s **veiled
> threat**: If the restaurant owner didn’t pick up on the implied meaning,
> he could create problems for himself. "[**Implicature** and the
> Interpretation of the Law (Part
> One)](https://philosophicaldisquisitions.blogspot.com/2012/12/implicature-and-interpretation-of-law.html)"

Comment: I lost my checkmark! Was that a case of premature checkulation?

Comment: It was done online, so it actually was  premature e-checkulation.

Answer (score 1):

Issuing a warning *or else* ​"that something unpleasant might happen to them"
is a **Thinly** [**Veiled Threat**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/veiled-threat).

**Examples**

- Not for its political points: [The New York Times reported](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/01/14/us/politics/nato-president-trump.html) seriously that President Trump's threats to withdraw from NATO sent officials scrambling to prevent the alliance from turning into a disaster. They did not see the *thinly veiled threat* as posturing ... for countries to pay their proportional NATO dues as the US did. [rephrased]

  But seen as a veiled threat, Trump's suggestion to withdraw was a
  warning, only: *I don't want to play in your yard, if you won't be
  good to me.* And if you can't bluff, you can't bargain.
- Even vanilla comments like "You got a nice family there" can take on sinister tones when serving as the punchline to a demand with hints of violence.

Comment: I began an answer for *veiled,* but took the OP's "It represents a type of communication where what the speaker intends to communicate is not actually what they say" as looking for a more general term.  I believe it was 
Ian McKellen who, wanting an  *honest* compliment backstage  for a colleague after a terrible performance, came up with "Well, that was quite something!" hoping, I presume, the veil stays put.